# Making feature layer selectable in ArcObjects Java without getting AutomationException 0x80004005?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, java

I am currently making a FeatureLayer from a resultset.

The feature layer seems to work properly and will display on the map.

However when I choose "select all" on my feature layer I get the following automation exception:

```
AutomationException: 0x80004005 - Unspecified error
at com.esri.arcgis.carto.FeatureLayer.selectFeatures(Unknown Source)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.actions.selection.SelectAllAction.doActionPerformed(SelectAllAction.java:32)
at cc.nisc.gui.action.NiscAction.actionPerformed(NiscAction.java:225)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
```

my relevant code is listed below:

```
 try {
        String sqliteFile = String.valueOf(mwfFileSystem.getFesDirectory()) + "\\query_exports\\" + queryName + ".sqlite";


        workspace = WorkspaceFactory.SQLITE.openFromFile(
                sqliteFile);

        IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer();
        featureLayer.setSelectable(true);
            featureLayer.setFeatureClassByRef(workspace.openFeatureClass(queryName));
        featureLayer.setName(queryName);
        ActiveMapContainer mapContainer = ActiveMapContainer.getInstance();

        mapContainer.getMap().addLayer(featureLayer);
    } catch (ArcEngineException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```